# Proving that every cellular complex is Hausdorff.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> **Definition** $:$ A cellular space is a topological space $X$, with a sequence of subspaces
> $$X^{(0)}\subseteq X^{(1)}\subseteq X^{(2)}\subseteq \cdots $$
> such that $X=\bigcup\limits_{n \geq 0} X^{(n)}$, with the following properties $:$
>
> $(1)$ $X^{(0)}$ is a discrete space.
>
> $(2)$  for each positive integer $n$, there is an index set $I_n$, and  continuous map $\varphi_{\alpha}^{(n)}: S^{n-1} \to X^{(n-1)}$ for each $\alpha \in I_n$ and disjoint copies $D^n_{\alpha}$ of $D^n$ (one for each $\alpha \in I_n$) by identifying the points $x$ and $\varphi_{\alpha}^n(x)$ for each $x\in S_{\alpha}^{n-1}$ and each $\alpha \in I_n.$
>
> $(3)$ A subset $Y$ of $X$ is closed iff $Y\cap X^{(n)}$ is closed in $X^{(n)},$ for each $n \geq 0.$

Now can we say that every cellular space is Hausdorff? If so how do I prove that?

Comment: See Appendix A of Hatcher's Algebraic topology textbook. Main point is to show the space is Normal. https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf

Comment: @love_sodam I don't understand his idea as to how did he construct $N_{\varepsilon} (A)$ for a subset $A$ of $X\ $?